# How Split Face Normal after 'make edge' between vertex in N-gon

Tags: modeling

I just start trying to 'make edge' between vertex in n-gon. but when I select the first half of the face, it still select the whole face. How do i split the face (*green X sign) into two different normal? Thank you :)
[image: Make Edge in N-gon]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To split the face select 2 opposite vertices on the face and use <kbd>J</kbd> button instead of <kbd>F</kbd> button, in your case you created an edge on top of the face.

Comment: Glad to know it, as simple as the answer. thank you Denis and @NovaNanite

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before, and the solution is fairly simple. Sometimes when you create an edge on a face the edge is only connected to the two points and not the face, so the line is a separate object from the face. (I still have no clue why this happens). To fix this all you should have to do is go back in to vertex select mode and select the two vertices you want to create an edge between and then press the F key to create an edge. I hope this helps and I'm sorry if you already tried this method to fix it.